# Why Doesnt PHP Parse My Scripts?

Tags: php, parsing, executable

I'm trying to get the php executable to parse scripts, but it's not working. i run something like this:

> php c:\test.php

and test.php contains this:

```
<?
echo 'hello!';
?>
```

and that is exactly what running the command returns. It returns the raw code. How can I get it to actually parse the code and return "hello!" instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have the [short_open_tag](https://www.php.net/ini.core#ini.short-open-tag) setting enabled in your php.ini. Failing that, use the ever-so-slightly longer `<?php` to start your script.

Answer (score 1):

Another option might be to try using the -f command line option.

```
php -f c:\test.php
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I've ran php off the command line, but try this:

```
<?php
echo 'hello!';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure that your webserver is correctly configured.  If it is not configured to run .php pages through the php interpreter it may simply display as a text file.